# Horizontal centered bootstrap button isnt centered on android browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, android-browser

im working on a flat portfolio site, im using bootstrap.

The btn-succes got a bonus class of

```
.center {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

on pc its perfectly aligned center (firefox and ie) but on mobile it seems to float left.
i tried diffrend things like change it to `inline-block` and to delete the `Width:40%` but nothing seems to work.

I got here the live site "jurjenfolkertsma.nl/bootstrap"

Hoping any of you guys could help me

Comment: try `margin: 0 auto;`. also, android browser may not work in prior versions

Comment: @DanielCheung not working for me ...

Comment: It seems like the buttons are centered on my Android device (HTC One)

Comment: @SunilD. the ones that are in the content slider are, but the first green one in the main content area (with the map marker icon) isnt for me (samsung galaxy advance)